# Minikube Start Stuck Pulling base image

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

[image]

I have been trying to setup minikube but the command is stuck at pulling base image since forever

Comment: it looks like you've to enter either p or s.

Comment: Entering p or s does not make any difference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not stuck; it is just not showing the output of the downloading progress. It's an 800 MB file, it takes time to download.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7012

Comment: Yes You are right it took time but it was done later On.

Answer (score 16):

If you are getting an error like **failed to download kic base image or any fallback image** run the following command

> minikube delete --all --purge

then start the cluster using **minikube start**

(Link to the original issue - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8997)

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

```bash
# Remove all old data
minikube delete

# start a fresh instance
minikube start

# Start with a different driver
minikube start --driver=<docker/hyperkit>
```

Comment: I had same issue and delete then start fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `docker driver`, you can also manually download the image.

Executing : `docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.32` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

@amolgautam [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73044107/6184776) worked for me as well. Only making a small addition in case if someone gets stuck

You need to add `--base-image` when executing the `minikube start` command in case if the image you downloaded is not the latest one being used by Minikube.

```
minikube start --base-image "gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.32"
```